# How to set month range according to Indian financial years

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date-range

According to Indian financial year(April-1 to March-31), how do i get range when month changed to January my logic fails after 31 December, nothing is displayed.Here is my code for displaying all months:
Model:

```
def self.get_month(month)
    months={
       '1'=> 'January',
       '2'=> 'February',      
       '3'=> 'March',
       '4'=> 'April',
       '5'=> 'May',
       '6'=> 'June',
       '7'=> 'July',
       '8'=> 'August',
       '9'=> 'September',
       '10'=> 'October',
       '11'=> 'November',
       '12' => 'December'
      }
   months[month]
 end
```

views:

```
<% (current_financial_year.start_date.month..Date.today.month).times do |a| %>
             <tr>
               <td><%= PayrollDetails.get_month(a.to_s)%></td>
             </tr>
             <% end %>
```

This code works well up to December month but in January when year changed it displays nothing, i got this error:

```
undefined method `times' for 4..1:Range
```

how do i fix this revers range problem in rails3,  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not handling the wrap case. There are many ways you could go about handling it. This is the most basic way I can think up:

```
<% (current_financial_year.start_date.month..(Date.today.month < current_financial_year.start_date.month ? Date.today.month+12 : Date.today.month)).times do |a| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= PayrollDetails.get_month((a%12).to_s)%></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is rather ugly. You might want to create a local variable for `current_month` or you could open up the `Date` class and define a financial month which does the `? :` logic.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Geoff this could be a new start for me

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Geoff s answer i have changed this little bit to fit in my condition:

```
 <% for a in (current_financial_year.start_date.month..(Date.today.month < current_financial_year.start_date.month ? Date.today.month+12 : Date.today.month)) %>
             <tr>
               <td><%= PayrollDetail.get_month((a>12? (a -12) : a ).to_s)%></td>
<% end %>
```

And this works for me.